# AWS S3 underscore workaround

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The situation: I have a bunch of images in an S3 bucket named with underscores (e.g. my_images)

However, when instantiating a Java client with Amazon's SDK (v 1.8.7)

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
amazonS3.createBucket("my_images");
```

I get an IllegalArgumentException. According to Amazon's documentation [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html),

> Bucket names should not contain underscores

Any workarounds for this? It is VERY annoying that Amazon would allow me to name a bucket with an underscore if it can't be accessed by the SDK.

Edit: I tried migrating to a bucket called myImages and

> Bucket names cannot contain uppercase characters

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I will have to migrate my entire bucket to a new name compliant bucket using the aws cli tool

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2
```

This naming consistency is being addressed by [Amazon](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2343)

Answer (score 0):

European region Bucket allows only lower case letters. Although Buckets created in the **US may contain both lower case and upper case**, Amazon **recommends** that you use all **lower case letters** when creating a bucket.

**For more details view [this page](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--amazon-s3-buckets-introduction.html)**